# What is the name of this type of wooden "fasteners"

Tags: fasteners

I was doing some work in the chicken coop today, and when it came time to attach the new wire mesh, I had the idea to use the little wooden tabs i had laying around from previous cuts as fasteners. Essentially, I am pinching the mesh to adhere it. It worked really well. However, I have no idea what this could be called. Does using wood like this have an existing name?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. I'm not sure if there's a formal name for these, but they're a type of cleat, or batten, both of which can be catch-all terms for thin/narrow strips of wood. And this type of thing might be (I think typically would be) referred to generically, e.g. "Secure the edges of the mesh by screwing on battens." Since the two words are interchangeable the sentence could just as easily end "...by screwing on cleats." if the person talking was from another woodworking tradition, or a different country (batten being more British English these days).

Comment: Incidentally there's another simple solution to this need that you might want to file away for future reference. You can use larger washers (fender washers) to spread the grip of individual screws — one screw sited in the middle of a square of the mesh could comfortably grip in all four directions with a washer of this type. And as this is a lower-profile option it's possibly handy for other applications in future.

Comment: This would be understood by most woodworkers as "cleats".

Comment: @jdv I was going to suggest you be wary of your American-English bias, but actually I think you're right because the number of native English speakers *is* highest in the US.

Comment: @Graphus names drift, of course. Both battens and cleats, in the nautical sense, don't describe what we see here, really. For me, a batten is intended to close the seam between two things. Maybe for this reason only I prefer cleat, that most overused of utility words.

Comment: (That is to say, regardless of where you grew up and learned English, you'd _probably_ at least recognize these items as being somewhat in the "cleat" family.)

Comment: We — that is to say, older woodworkers who use British English — often go out of our way not to make use of American terminology (even if correct, which increasingly it is not q.v. widespread miss-use of splines). I'm not so stuck in the past that I insist on *cramp* instead of *clamp*, but I'd prefer to use batten (the traditional English term) over cleat as much as possible. Even French cleats have another name in British woodworking circles.... which uses neither French (they're not from France!) *or* cleat LOL

Comment: @Graphus Let's not investigate the way the English language on either side of the Atlantic (and beyond) has insisted something is "French"! (or Norwegian, or German, ...) Also, apropos: https://thewoodknack.blogspot.com/2018/04/confusing-woodworking-terms-apron-vs.html

Comment: @jdv. and don't get me started on "Danish" oil! LOL [Although the origin of the name does make some sense historically, that it stuck around and became part of the lexicon does not so much (to me at least) when, at most, it should have been the makings of an interesting footnote.]

Comment: @jdv, thanks for the link BTW, just read it! Some great examples there (many more than I'd have been able to reference) but it's interesting, I wouldn't think *apron* and *stretcher* are synonymous. Without being consciously aware of how or where I learned it (New Yankee Workshop?) the way I understand the term apron — and this appears to be nearly universal — is the entire underside structure not including the legs, so both rails and stretchers. Oh and P.S. dado = *housing* in most contexts in British parlance, surprised he didn't include that.

Comment: I'll be thinking "split battens" every time I install my "french cleats" this week-end.